# Tradingview Pinescript - series string and plot error

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, trading

I was trying to extend the pivot lines for extra 10 days, but there is some mistake in the code, which I am not able to figure out

It says:

> Cannot call 'plot' with argument 'title'='call 'operator +' (series string)'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected.

[image]

I am trying to create a code to extend the pivot line for 10 days, if the lines are not touched during the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggest you where using a series string but you need a const string. A series are most values, we can access those via `[]` behind the variable name. You can read about it [HERE](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Time_series.html).

In the picture you were trying to put such a value inside `plot(title = "my series value")` which is not allowed. You need a const value instead. A const value is a fixed value since beginning of the script and it never changes it value.

**This are examples of const values...**

```
float  my_variable = 1234
string my_string   = "Hello World!"
```

Those values are fixed for the whole duration of the script, unless you change them later, but than it isn't a const any more.

**Example for series...**

```
float my_variable := my_variable + 1  // change const into series
float my_old_value = my_variable[1]   // pure series
```

**Example for simple...**

```
float my_string = str.format("{0} {1}", "Hello", my_variable > 1234 ? "Simple" : "World!")
```

---

When you need this `loop` in the picture, then you have to change plots into `line.new()`, cause plots need to be in global scope, and `loops` create local scopes. [HERE](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/User-defined_functions.html?highlight=global%20scope#scopes-in-the-script) you can read about scopes.

I assume you could use `plot()` within global scope in combination with `?:`.

```
plot(is_true ? value : na, ..., style = plot.style_linebr)
```

You can read about `?:` [HERE](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#ternary-operator).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `plot()` in local scope.

If you want to do something like that, you should use [line](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Lines_and_boxes.html#lines).

Basically, create a line with `line.new()` and add 10 day to its `x2` argument. Then update its coordinates with `line.set_*()` functions.