# How to plot a value in the indicator status line when a condition is met and don't plot anything when the condition is not met?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'd like to plot the value of RSW_band_cross_final variable in the indicator status line if it equals to 1 and don't plot anything if it equals to 0, instead of seeing the value 0.00 in the status line. Is it even possible? Or is there any workaround? Thank you.

```
RSW_positive_band_cross = RSW >= band
RSW_negative_band_cross = RSW <= -band
```

Conversion from bool to int:

```
int RSW_band_cross_final = na 
if RSW_positive_band_cross == true or RSW_negative_band_cross == true
    RSW_band_cross_final := 1
else
    RSW_band_cross_final := 0
```

The following plot line returns an error: `"Cannot call 'operator ?:' with argument 'expr0'='call 'operator ==' (series bool)'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'const bool' is expected."` in the `"display = RSW_band_cross_final == 1"` part of the line.

```
plot(RSW_band_cross_final, title = "Relative Strength / Weakness Status Line Value", color = RSW_positive_band_cross == true ? color.new(#00d99f, 0) : RSW_negative_band_cross == true ? color.new(#ff004d, 0) : na, editable = false, display = RSW_band_cross_final == 1 ? display.status_line : display.none)
```

**EDIT:**
Based on the provided answer it seems that it's not possible to do.

Possible "workarounds" are:

1. Return `na` if the condition is false, instead of a `0`, as Mario
   pointed out. This way there would be a `Ø` character in the
   indicator status line which takes less space than `0.00` (or whatever precision does the script use).
2. Keep returning `0` if the condition is false. This way there would be `0.00` in the indicator status line, but it's possible to change the text color to match the chart background, so that it would be almost invisible (the color of the `Ø` character (`na` value) cannot be changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change status line to `on` or `off` while the script is running.
That is the reason of the error message and it is asking for a `const bool` instead.

In the case you want to know what a const value is, look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77210203/7644275).

Instead of using the value zero you could use `na`,
but it still would show something in the status line.